# How can I embed windows media player without the visualizations

Tags: browser, audio, embed, wmp

I enjoyed the late 90s just as much as the last guy, but I'd like to be able to play an audio file on a web page without having to look at the cheesy geometric visualizations that wmp shows.  Is there a good way of doing this?  Here's my code:

```
<object classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
    <param name="url" value="file.wav" />
    <param name="autoStart" value="True" />
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="file.wav" name="MediaPlayer">
    </embed>
</object>
```

One temporary solution I've found is to set the `height` parameter to 45, which ends up showing just the controls at the bottom.  As soon as Microsoft decides to change their layout though, this won't look right.  Argh!